# How to use $emit inside .then of an Axios request in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have a method inside a Vue component like this:

```js
submitForm() {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", this.file);
    const config = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
    };

    this.axios
        .post(
            "http://localhost/api.php",
            formData,
            config
        )
        .then(function(data) {
            this.$emit("serverReturnedData", data);
        })
        .catch(function() {
            console.log("FAILURE!!");
        });
}
```

But the `this.$emit("serverReturnedData", data)` is not working.

And this is the `api.php`. It just moves the uploaded file and returns an url pointing to that file.

```php
<?php
  
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
  
    $file_type = $_FILES["file"]["type"];

    $allowed = array("application/pdf");
    if(!in_array($file_type, $allowed)) {
    $error_message = 'Only pdf files are allowed.';
    } elseif (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/".$_FILES['file']['name'])) {
        echo "http://localhost/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        exit;
    }
  
    echo "failed";
  
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure that your client successfully executes the request.

Then, use arrow function instead of an anonymous function definition to handle `then` result of the promise. Now `this` context will refer to your component.

```
submitForm() {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("file", this.file);
  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
  };

  this.axios
    .post(
      "http://localhost/api.php",
      formData,
      config
    )
    .then((data) => { // like this
      this.$emit("serverReturnedData", data);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log("FAILURE!!");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [hoangdv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5196394/hoangdv) said you should use an arrow function in the [then](/questions/tagged/then) clause. Also consider using kebab-case for the naming of events as advised in the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html).

And finally, how are you listening to this custom event in the parent component? It should be something like:

```
<parent-component v-on:your-custom-event="someJavascript" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if for some reason you don't want to use an arrow function, you can write it like this

```
submitForm() {
    let formData = new FormData();
    let self = this; // <<<<< like this
    formData.append("file", this.file);
    const config = {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
        }
    };

    this.axios
        .post(
            "http://localhost/api.php",
            formData,
            config
        )
        .then(function(data) {
            self.$emit("serverReturnedData", data);
        })
        .catch(function() {
            console.log("FAILURE!!");
        });
}
```

Comment: Well i don't want to, But still thank you for suggesting!